# Add syntax highlighting for the system-verilog tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Please add the same syntax highlighting as the [verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog) tag to the [system-verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-verilog) tag for consistency.  Currently, `verilog` has syntax highlighting, but `system-verilog` does not.  The [system-verilog tag info](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/system-verilog/info) aptly states that it "is a backwards-compatible superset of verilog".  Thus, it makes sense for both to use the same highlighting.

Several questions are tagged with both, and the highlighting looks fine.  For example,
[this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572251/generate-for-loop-lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay on this one.

To answer your question, **yes**, I have found where I could change the syntax highlighter for the `system-verilog` tag (currently none), to match the `verilog` tag highlighting.

However as kindly explained in [this answer from MarkU](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8550), the syntax highlighting module being used for the `verilog` tag is called "lang-vhdl". There is no syntax highlighter specifically for Verilog (or System Verilog) available for me to choose. (The SE decision not to include Verilog & System Verilog highlighting in the SE-specific `highlight.js` is stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354029).)

Before my upvote for usefulness, that answer from MarkU had 1 downvote and 0 upvotes (and no explanatory comment for the downvote) - so was the original downvote to that answer, because there is some big negative consequence to the proposed change which no-one else has mentioned?

**Summary:**

I believe I can make the change you requested, but the downvote on that answer pointing out that it will invoke the `lang-vhdl` highlighting, is puzzling. Further feedback would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand you mods are very busy.  Yes, I understand the verilog tag currently uses vhdl highlighting.  Someone else long ago must've decided the vhdl highlighting was good enough for verilog, too; I agree with that, and I assume the rest of the users here have had no problem with it over the years.  Regrading the other 2 answers, they seem to have taken this simple request off onto other tangents, unfortunately.  I intentionally kept my request brief in my Question.  Since the Question has only upvotes, no one strongly disagrees with the request....

Comment: ...  Shall I update the Question with more details?  I think it would be beneficial for the verilog and system-verilog tags to be consistent with each other regarding highlighting.  My request is that you make the change since only Moderators can make this change.

Comment: @toolic - Hi, I don't think more details are needed in the question - if `lang-vhdl` syntax highlighting is as good as we can get (and it will match the `verilog` tag behaviour) then I can enable that same syntax highlighting on the `system-verilog` tag now. OK?

Comment: Yes, please do enable the same highlighting.  I think it's good enough.

Comment: @toolic - OK, I've now enabled that. I can now see some (limited) highlighting on a couple of SV questions I just checked. Can you please look at some SV questions and confirm that (some) syntax highlighting is working for you too? Thanks.

Comment: I looked at a few SV-only posts with code, and they have syntax highlighting look as expected.  Thanks once again.

Comment: @toolic - Great, thanks for your help, I'll consider this topic resolved. Could you please accept this answer if you agree? And sorry again for the delay. Sincere regards...

Comment: Accepted!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

As of 2020-09-24, all stack exchange sites use [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/) for code-formatting and syntax-highlighting, see
[Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter)

The list of languages supported by highlight.js is at https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md and verilog and VHDL are both on the list.

For some strange reason, tag [verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog) is configured to use the **lang-vhdl** highlighter:

> https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/verilog/info
> Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-vhdl

I don't know why. The highlight.js posted on github has separate options for verilog and vhdl, but stackoverflow [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) mentions that they use their own fork of this library, and don't have all of the modules installed. At any rate, if the lang-vhdl highlighter is working well enough for verilog, I suppose it would work for system verilog just as well, right?

Is it possible for one of our local site moderators to edit the [system-veriog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-veriog) tag's *Code Language* field to match the verilog and vhdl tags (i.e. lang-vhdl)? Or is this something that requires the whole meta feature-request route to the stackexchange community managers?

Comment: MarkU - Hi, I don't know if you're following this question, so this comment is just to mention that I've added an answer which builds on yours. Yes, I could change that highlighting for the `system-verilog` tag to match the `verilog` tag (without needing to involve the CMs, as far as I can tell). But the downvote on your answer is puzzling, and I wonder if that is someone indicating a flaw in that plan that we haven't spotted :-( Feedback on my answer is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One other (labor-intensive) way to mitigate this lack of code highlighting for questions tagged [system-verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-verilog) but not [verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog) would be to edit each question so that its code blocks are introduced with

```` ```verilog ```` (whatever highlighter tag [verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog) uses)

or

```` ```lang-verilog ```` (use verilog highlighter, regardless of the tag default highlighter)

instead of just ```` ``` ```` (which uses the tag default highlighter).

Just trying that out here, maybe the syntax highlighting doesn't work on meta?

```
# example code using default highlighter
module abc(input net d, output reg e)
assign e = d
endmodule
```

```
-- example code using lang-vhdl
module abc(input net d, output reg e)
assign e = d
endmodule
```

```
# example code using lang-verilog
module abc(input net d, output reg e)
assign e = d
endmodule
```

```
-- example code using same highlighting as tag:vhdl
module abc(input net d, output reg e)
assign e = d
endmodule
```

```
# example code using same highlighting as tag:verilog
module abc(input net d, output reg e)
assign e = d
endmodule
```

```
# example code using same highlighting as tag:system-verilog
module abc(input net d, output reg e)
assign e = d
endmodule
```